# Flink: Shuffle with Parallelism = 1

Tags: apache-flink

I am running `Flink` on only one node with `Parallelism = 1` in order to compare its performance with a single-threaded application. I'm wondering if `Flink` is still using a `Shuffle` although it does not run in parallel. So if e.g. the following command is executed:

```scala
var counts = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") filter { _.nonEmpty } }
  .map { (_, 1) }
  .groupBy(0)
  .sum(1)
```

Will a `Shuffle` be used before the `groupBy`? And is there a way to check this?

(In the output of the Interactive `Scala Shell` there is a `FlatMap`, `Map`, `Combine` and finally a `Reduce` to observe. The same applies when running with `Parallelism > 1`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink generates for the operation `ds.groupBy(0).sum(1)` the job graph `... -> Combiner -> Reducer` independent of the actual parallelism. Between the `Combiner` and the `Reducer` there is a hash partitioner (shuffle step) introduced. This makes sense for all `parallelism > 1`.

For `parallelism = 1`, the optimizer could theoretically remove the shuffle step, because it is not necessary. However, it should actually not affect the performance of the program.

The reason is that for `parallelism = 1` all work will be done in the local combiner. This means that the combiner calculates the resulting sum and then only sends a single element to the reducer. Furthermore, since the combiner and the reducer run on the same machine, there is no network communication involved. The data is simply transferred by handing over a memory segment. Since Flink also supports streamed shuffling, the combiner does not even have to finish before the first results can be sent to the reducer. Both, the combiner and the reducer, can run at the same time, thus avoiding the materialization of intermediate results.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You are writing "Between the `Combiner` and the `Reducer` there is a **hash partitioner** (shuffle step) introduced." Does Flink always use hashing when shuffling?

Comment: The key of the elements is used to find out on which machine elements with the same key are aggregated. In order to do that, the hash of the key element is calculated. Flink then applies the MurmurHash modulo the number of nodes to finally decide to which node the element will be sent.

Comment: OK, that is also a useful information but  I actually meant something else. On some systems it is possible for a user to choose a shuffling implementation (e.g. choose between hash and sort). Does Flink also allow that or is the hashing strategy always used?

Comment: Since Flink executes its shuffles in a pipelined fashion, there is no such thing as sorting the data before shuffling it. Thus, it's always the hashing strategy used.